# asp.net cron job quartz.net bug, not firing always

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a job, which triggers in every 30 minutes. I've set a test table and record information, when job fires. For example :

```
2015-12-13 19:30:00.043
2015-12-14 12:30:00.043
2015-12-14 13:00:00.043
2015-12-14 16:00:00.043
```

But as you can see it does not trigger in  every 30 minutes. 19:30 then 12:30..  I've noticed that if i open managament studio and check this table, next job would trigger 100%. Why is that happening, is it quartz.net bug? 
P.S i am using asp.net mvc and this is code :

```
  ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
                     (s =>
                        s.WithIntervalInMinutes(30)
                        .OnEveryDay()
                       .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
                     )
                   .Build();

               scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Answer (score 1):

Needs to change `WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule` to `WithSimpleSchedule`. Warning: there are probably better ways to deal with `startDate`.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, 0 ,0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

 ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
.StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(startDate, new TimeSpan(0)))
.WithSimpleSchedule
(s =>
    s.WithIntervalInMinutes(30)
    .RepeatForever()
)                   
.Build();
```

Test:

```
var times = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(trigger as IOperableTrigger, null, 10);

foreach (var time in times)
    Console.WriteLine(time.UtcDateTime);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Result:

```
14.12.2015 15:00:00
14.12.2015 15:30:00
14.12.2015 16:00:00
14.12.2015 16:30:00
14.12.2015 17:00:00
14.12.2015 17:30:00
14.12.2015 18:00:00
14.12.2015 18:30:00
14.12.2015 19:00:00
14.12.2015 19:30:00
```

Comment: Let's obsarve 3-4 days  and see what would happen

Comment: I think I don't quite understand the comment, but if you want to observe 4 days you can just change `10` (which are 10 intervals of 30min) to `4 days * 24 h/day * 2 intevals/h`, that is to say: `192`. The result is as expected: 192 intevals separated by 30min in a span of 4 days.

Comment: I will use hangfire, quartz.net not working as expecting